# Visual Studio Community freezes on creating new Xamarin project on macOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I tried to create a "HelloWorld" project with Xamarin on macOS and the wizard stops on the following step:

[image: The wizard window where it stops]

I can see that in the background it's initializing my new project - I can see the Solution panel with new files appearing but the wizard window can't be dismissed. I waited enough time in my opinion so I should have it finished. I suppose that it might be hanging because of some permissions or networking timeout - I was using "**Native App (iOS, Android)**" template.

Is there anything I can do to avoid it? When I closed the wizard window, it looked that I had a incompletely initialized project: a lot of packages was missing, so I guess it might be something connected to networking timeouts or permissions.

When I added those Packages, my iOS target works fine, but I still have a problem with Android.

Comment: Seen this before on macOS (I've reported it multiple times and MS has closed it multiple times, seems you have a glitch-free network connection (per the responses that I have gotten...)  , if Nuget hangs, typically due to high latency network connection and/or a high transport error rate, solution/project creation can hang the entire VS4M process and cause template strange errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to start it from scratch and it turned out to fix my problems with dependencies and freezing on a project's initialization.

I suppose that adding packages manually **unlocked something that blocked automatic package adding on startup**. Previously when I tried to go with the wizard several times in row I got the same result - it froze on initialization and the dependencies were missing. Now when I use the same template, it works fine every time.

That's weird but maybe it will help someone. When it hangs on initialization of a template and the dependencies are missing, **try to add them manually and then init from the template again**.